# "For three years" vs "in three years"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, prepositions, time, in-for

> - I haven't talked to my wife **for** three years.
> - I haven't talked to my wife **in** three years.

Are *in* and *for* interchangeable in these sentences?

Comment: My idea of differentiation-I haven't talked ....for 3 years: You did not want to talk. If You talk with someone in years- it may imply that you did not get the opportunity to talk.

Answer (score 0):

Effectively, in that situation they are.  The meaning each is conveying is thus:

> I haven't talked to my wife for a running period of 3 years [as if you were timing it from the beginning]

and

> I haven't talked to my wife in the period prior which was 3 years

As you can see the meaning is still practically the same, but they are built from slightly different ways of looking at the period of time.